# List of Tuples to store on pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have few hundreds text files that I am reading as list of tuples below.

```
file_1= [(),(),(),(),()...]
file_2= [(),(),(),(),()...]
.
.
.
file_n= [(),(),(),(),()...]
```

Now I want to add these into pyspark dataframe something like below

```
+------+------------------------+
|file_1 |     [(),(),(),(),()...]|
|file_2 |     [(),(),(),(),()...]| 
 .
 .
 .
|file_n |     [(),(),(),(),()...]|
+------+------------------------+
```

How can i achieve this or if there is even  a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if the content of your text file is like this 
    file_1= [(),(),(),(),()...]

And, if you are using spark 2 Then you can use csv to convert it into data frame:

```
df = spark.read.csv("file path", sep = " = ")
```

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand your response